# Get usage status from AWS API key

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-key, serverless

I have an [AWS serverless API configured with a usage plan](https://s.natalian.org/2018-04-12/1523514443.mp4). I want users to be able to know how many more requests they can make, so they are don't get stuck with:

```
HTTP/2 429
content-type: application/json
content-length: 28
date: Mon, 16 Apr 2018 03:41:12 GMT
x-amzn-requestid: 02436b06-4128-11e8-aa37-8f617035a300
x-amzn-errortype: LimitExceededException
x-cache: Error from cloudfront
via: 1.1 de2aa82ec56d0a6d749df4bf0a88b28f.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: afyULHDbLwJYAJO07zLeFG1Q0tZA-VhB3kezRgE1UBldQdfaGRQaZQ==
{"message":"Limit Exceeded"}
```

I've been looking over AWS documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/index.html#cli-aws-apigateway & https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/apigateway/

And I can't seem to figure out how to tell how many requests an API key is allowed to make! My goal is to see present user's something like Twitter's:

```
x-rate-limit-limit: 1500
x-rate-limit-remaining: 1499
x-rate-limit-reset: 1523850782
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the usage data of a usage plan in a specified time interval for an "optional" specific API key via [usage:get](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/link-relation/usage-get/):

```
GET /usageplans/<usageplanId>/usage{?keyId,startDate,endDate,limit}
```

The returned [usage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/usage/) data represents **daily** logs of used and remaining quotas, over the specified time interval indexed over the API keys in the usage plan.

(Similar implementations are available in AWS SDKs)

Source: [Amazon API Gateway REST API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/).